# Verilog code synthesis error

Tags: verilog, synthesis, code

I'm having problem with my verilog code when I synthesize it. It shows multiple drivers error. I think may be it's because of multiple always blocks I'm using in it. So how can I fix it!!? Here it is:

```
module check(csx,dcx,wrx,rdx,clk,d_out,res);
input wire clk,res;
output reg csx,dcx,wrx,rdx;
output reg [7:0]d_out;
reg [2:0]count;

always @ (res)
begin
  if (res==1)
  begin
    csx=1;
    wrx=0;
    rdx=1;
    dcx=0;
    count=0;
    d_out=0;
  end
end

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  count=count+1;
end

always @ (count)
begin
  repeat(3'h5)
  begin
    if((count+res)==3'h2)
    begin
      d_out=8'h28;
    end
    else if(count==3'h3)
    begin
      csx=0;
      wrx=1;
    end
    else if (count==3'h4)
    begin
      wrx=0;
      csx=1;
      d_out=8'h11;
    end
    else if (count==3'h5)
    begin
      csx=0;
      wrx=1;
    end
  end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the reset logic as a separate `always` block; you need to incorporate the reset into the blocks you already have.

Also, you can't use the `repeat` block that way in synthesizable code. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish with it; it looks like you could simply delete that line and the associated `end` line.

Answer (score 0):

To be synthesisable, `reg` types can only be assigned within one `always` block. Verilog allows `reg`s to be assigned anywhere for test bench and non-synthesiable modeling purposes.

`repeat` is a non-synthesiable keyword. Again, it is for test benches and non-synthesiable modeling.

The `always @ (count)` block is inferring latching logic for two reasons:

1. The sensitivity list is incomplete. It should be `always @ (count or res)` or `always @*`
2. `csx,dcx,wrx,rdx,d_out` are not assigned in every branched condition, this infers latches.

Most likely you want to put in one always block and have `csx,dcx,wrx,rdx,d_out` be flops:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge res) // clock edge or async reset
begin
  if (rst == 1'b1) begin // reset
    // assign all regs a constant default value
    csx <= 1'b1; // use non-blocking assignment (<=)
    wrx <= 1'b0; // recommenced to use to use explicit bit-width and radix
    // ...
  end
  else begin
    case (count)
      3'd1: d_out=8'h28;
      3'd2: begin
              csx=0;
              wrx=1;
            end
      // ... other conditions 
    endcase
    count <= count + 1'd1;
  end
```

If your simulator and synthesizer support SystemVerilog, I'd recommend using the `always_ff` (for flip-flops), `always_comb` (for combination logic) and `always_latch` (for intended latches). They are like the traditional `always` expect they throw compiling errors if more than one `always*` block is assigning the same register, if blocking delay elements are found withing the block, and additional checks for synthesisablity. It also give improved guidance to linting and logical equivalency checking tools. It will give the same result as properly coded Verilog.